# Program Crashes When Declaring Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, memory, crash

I have a small chunk of C++ code that involves declaring some arrays of size 200005. When I run my code, it crashes right away. However, when I change `const ll MX = 200005` to `const ll MX = 20005`, that is, change the size of the three arrays to each be **20005** instead of **200005**, my program runs without crashing. Why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;
const ll MX = 200005;

int main() {
    ll n; cin >> n;
    ll x[MX], y[MX], v[MX];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's more data than can fit on your stack.

Comment: How is this possible? I've created arrays of size 1 Million and greater before!

Comment: It depends on the system you ran it on, and the size of the data types in the array.

Comment: Would using a vector support this size?

Comment: Oh yes, a `vector` will allocate from the heap, so you have a lot more memory to work with.

Comment: Thank you, I will use vector.

Comment: The size here is almost 5 million bytes.